# Не открывается страница php по ссылке

Tags: php, html

> Прикладываю первый документ в котором находится ссылка на страницу php.

```
<?php


$Page['title'] = 'Выбрать дом';
$Page['description'] = 'Выбрать дом';
$Page['keywrods'] = 'Выбрать дом';

$Page['html'] = '
<div class="inner">
    <div class="main_map"></div>
    <div class="main_sale_count">61<br><br>объект<br>в продажу</div>
    <a href="/" class="main_logo"></a>
    <a href="booklet.pdf" target="_blank" class="main_download_buklet">Скачать буклет</a>
    <div class="main_contacts">
        <div>8 (921) 558 70 52</div>

        <button onclick="showCallme();">Заказать звонок</button>

 </div>

    <h1 class="main">
    <center>
<table border="1" width="30%" height="100">

    <tr>
 <br>
    <td><a href="townhouses.php"align="center"style="text-decoration:none;color: #CD5C5C">Таунхаусы</a></td>
    <td><a href="cottages.php"align="center"style="text-decoration:none;color: #CD5C5C">Коттеджи</a></td>
    <td><a href=""align="center"style="text-decoration:none;color: #CD5C5C">Квартиры</a></td>
    <td><a href=""align="center"style="text-decoration:none;color: #CD5C5C">Апартаменты</a></td>
    </tr>
</table> 
</center>
</h1>

    <br><br><br>

    <div class="p_text" style="padding: 300px 30px 0 30px;">

        <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">

            <tr>
                <td width="20%"><img src="images/img_cottages/1/1.1.png" width="170" /></td>
                <td width="30%">
                    <h2>Тип 1</h2>
                    <p>Площадь: 194,1 кв.м</p>
                    <a href="cottages1" style="color: #fff;">Узнать подробнее</a>
                </td>
                <td width="20%"><img src="images/img_cottages/2/2.1.png" width="170" /></td>
                <td width="30%">
                    <h2>Тип 2</h2>
                    <p>Площадь: 140,2 кв.м</p>
                    <a href="cottages2" style="color: #fff;">Узнать подробнее</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4"><div style="height: 2px; background: #c6c6c6; margin: 20px 0;"></div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="20%"><img src="images/img_cottages/3/3.png" width="170" /></td>
                <td width="30%">
                    <h2>Тип 3</h2>
                    <p>Площадь: 174,1 кв.м</p>
                    <a href="cottages3" style="color: #fff;">Узнать подробнее</a>
                </td>

                <td width="20%"><img src="images/img_cottages/4/4.1.png" width="170" /></td>
                <td width="30%">
                    <h2>Тип 4</h2>
                    <p>Площадь: 174 кв.м</p>
                    <a href="cottages4" style="color: #fff;">Узнать подробнее</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4"><div style="height: 2px; background: #c6c6c6; margin: 20px 0;"></div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="20%"><img src="images/img_cottages/5/5.1.png" width="170" /></td>
                <td width="30%">
                    <h2>Тип 5</h2>
                    <p>Площадь: 211,7 кв.м</p>
                    <a href="cottages5" style="color: #fff;">Узнать подробнее</a>
                </td>
                <td width="20%"><img src="images/img_cottages/6/6 .png" width="170" /></td>
                <td width="30%">
                    <h2>Тип 6</h2>
                    <p>Площадь: 214,6 кв.м</p>
                    <a href="cottages6" style="color: #fff;">Узнать подробнее</a>
                </td>

            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
';
```

> В следующем кусочке кода осуществляется конкретно привязка которая не срабатывает при нажатии на ссылку уже на самом сайте.

```
<h2>Тип 1</h2>
                    <p>Площадь: 194,1 кв.м</p>
                    <a href="cottages1" style="color: #fff;">Узнать подробнее</a>
                </td>
                <td width="20%"><img src="images/img_cottages/2/2.1.png" width="170" /></td>
                <td width="30%">
```

> Код страницы "cottages1" которая по неизвестным причинам не хочет отображаться.

```
<?

$Page['title'] = 'Коттедж Тип 1';
$Page['description'] = 'Коттедж Тип 1';
$Page['keywrods'] = 'Коттедж Тип 1';

$Page['html'] = '
<div class="inner">
    <div class="main_map"></div>
    <div class="main_sale_count">61<br><br>объект<br>в продажу</div>
    <a href="/" class="main_logo"></a>
    <a href="booklet.pdf" target="_blank" class="main_download_buklet">Скачать буклет</a>
    <div class="main_contacts">
        <div>8 (921) 558 70 52</div>
        <div>244 66 66</div>
                <button onclick="showCallme();">Заказать звонок</button>
    </div>

    <div class="p_quality">
        <div class="text">

            <div class="rama">
                <a href="cottages" style="float: right; color: #fff; font-size: 20px; margin-top: 30px;">Назад</a>
                <div class="header-txt">Коттедж Тип 1</div>

                <div style="text-align: center;">
                    <img src="images/img_cottages/1/1.1.png">
                    <p style="text-align: center;margin: 0;font-size: 20px;">Главный фасад</p>
                </div>
                <div style="text-align: center;">
                    <img src="images/img_cottages/1/1.1.png" >
                    <p style="text-align: center;margin: 0;font-size: 20px;">Вид с заднего двора</p>
                </div>

                <div class="header-txt">Планировки</div>
                <img src="images/Tip_1.png" width="100%" />
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
';
```

> Файл ".htaccess"

```
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteRule / index.php?page=about [L]
#RewriteRule ^index.php index.php?page=about [L]
RewriteRule ^about index.php?page=about [L]
RewriteRule ^benefits index.php?page=benefits [L]
RewriteRule ^location index.php?page=location [L]
RewriteRule ^promotions index.php?page=promotions [L]
RewriteRule ^quality index.php?page=quality [L]
RewriteRule ^houses index.php?page=houses [L]
RewriteRule ^house1 index.php?page=house1 [L]
RewriteRule ^house2 index.php?page=house2 [L]
RewriteRule ^house3 index.php?page=house3 [L]
RewriteRule ^house4 index.php?page=house4 [L]
RewriteRule ^house5 index.php?page=house5 [L]
RewriteRule ^house6 index.php?page=house6 [L]
RewriteRule ^contacts index.php?page=contacts [L]
RewriteRule ^townhouses index.php?page=townhouses [L]
RewriteRule ^cottages index.php?page=cottages [L]
RewriteRule ^cottages1 index.php?page=cottages1 [L]
RewriteRule ^cottages2 index.php?page=cottages2 [L]
RewriteRule ^cottages3 index.php?page=cottages3 [L]
RewriteRule ^cottages4 index.php?page=cottages4 [L]
RewriteRule ^cottages5 index.php?page=cottages5 [L]
RewriteRule ^cottages6 index.php?page=cottages6 [L]
RewriteRule ^cottages7 index.php?page=cottages7 [L]
RewriteRule ^cottages8 index.php?page=cottages8 [L]
RewriteRule ^cottages9 index.php?page=cottages9 [L]
RewriteRule ^cottages10 index.php?page=cottages10 [L]
RewriteRule ^cottages11 index.php?page=cottages11 [L]
RewriteRule ^cottages12 index.php?page=cottages12 [L]
RewriteRule ^cottages13 index.php?page=cottages13 [L]
RewriteRule ^cottages14 index.php?page=cottages14 [L]
RewriteRule ^cottages15 index.php?page=cottages15 [L]
RewriteRule ^cottages16 index.php?page=cottages16 [L]
RewriteRule ^cottages17 index.php?page=cottages17 [L]
RewriteRule ^cottages18 index.php?page=cottages18 [L]
```

Comment: В "cottages1" я не вижу echo() или print() - без них ничего не выведется. Может эта страница как-то обрабатывается другим скриптом? Есть ли сообщения об ошибках? А если включить сообщения об ошибках?

Comment: echo и print не помогают, пробовал по разному.  Документ остаётся на той же странице, но меняется адрес в строке. Как включить сообщения об ошибках?

Comment: а если страница обрабатывается скриптом, то как проследить путь к данному скрипту?

Comment: Ещё есть файл ".htaccess" может в нём что-то не так указано

Comment: `RewriteRule ^cottages1 index.php?page=cottages1` - то есть обработчик index.php. Включите в нем ошибки, например так https://karashchuk.com/PHP/error_reporting-display_errors-display_startup_errors/

Comment: Конкретно на этой странице  ошибок не обнаружено.